# how to show custom error in django instead of its default error?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

i have put restriction on **FileField** that the user can only upload **.doc, .pdf, .docx** format, but when user try to upload a different format's file then it's showing this screen:

[image: validation error]

If the user upload doc or pdf file format then the form should submit successfully else it should show my own custom error.

Comment: This is an actual Python exception; not the validation error you expect. Edit your question to include the source code for your `clean_Resume` function.

Comment: @Selcuk when i am uploading doc or pdf file then there is no exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem here is that your code is invalid. You didn't import `ValidationError`in your `app/forms.py`

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
```

Comment: @ Sardorbek Imomaliev when i am importing it is shwing me error **from django.core.exceptions import ValdationError
ImportError: cannot import name ValdationError**

Comment: @MonuThakur Sorry typo. Should be `ValidationError`. Try updated answer

Comment: Sorry i didn't get you

Comment: @MonuThakur there was mistake in answer, I fixed it, try copy and pasting again